# Multiple jQuery Validation remote in a single element

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to do 2 ajax call for validation in a single element. This is what I came out so far.

My html:

```
<form id="xForm" method="post" action="/someurl">
    <input id="oUrl" name="oUrl" type="text" />
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

My javascript:

```
$('#xForm').validate({
   rules:{
       oUrl:{
           required:true,
           minlength:4,
           maxlength:20,
           remoteA:'/register/checkValidUrl',
           remoteB:'/register/checkUrlAvailable'
      }
   },
   messages:{
      oUrl:{
          remoteA:'Url not valid',
          remoteB:'Url already been taken'
      }
   }
});
```

Actually I have 2(two) remote url to check on. Most of example I saw only use 1(one) remote site. So how do I achieve this?

The reason I do this because I simply cannot find a way to make a custom validator on which the server site return an error message, and on the client side uses it.

Comment: The [tag:jquery-validation-engine] plugin is not the same thing that you are using.  Please take more care when using the tags.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?  Just do it all on the server one time instead of two.  Your question is written poorly and makes no sense with respect to your code. Your code shows rules without any field names which is broken syntax for this plugin. Please see [sscce.org](http://sscce.org) and [items #1 and 2 on this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for tips on writing a better question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Quote OP**:  *"I want to do two ajax calls for validation in a single element."*

1. Why?
2. And no, you cannot.

It would look like this and it would be very broken...

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules:{
        myField: {  // <-- rules are assigned by field 'name'
            remote: '/register/checkValidUrl',
            remote: '/register/checkUrlAvailable'
        }
    }
});
```

However, when you send the field value to your server-side script the first time, simply check to see if it passes all necessary data validations there, and there's no need to send the same thing up there again.  In other words, there is no practical or logical reason to send the same value to the server two times.

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules:{
        myField: {  // <-- rules are assigned by field 'name'
            remote: '/register/checkUrl'
        }
    }
});
```

As per the documentation, if you send back `true` from your server, the field will pass validation.  If you send back a string, the field fails validation and that string becomes your error message.  In this way, you can send the value to the server once and validate it as many different ways as needed.

Your server-side code, (translate into whatever language you need)...

```
if invalid URL             
   echo JSON "url is invalid"         // fails validation      
else if unavailable URL    
   echo JSON "url is not available"   // fails validation
else if URL is purple    
   echo JSON "url must not be purple" // fails validation
else                      
   echo JSON TRUE                     // passes validation
```

[See documentation:](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)

> The **response** is evaluated as JSON and must be `true` for valid elements,
>   and can be any `false`, `undefined` or `null` for invalid elements, using
>   the default message; **OR A STRING**, eg. *"That name is already taken, try
>   peter123 instead"* to display as the error message.

Comment: how would this work for multiple fields that all have to be validated remotely??

Comment: @greaterKing, there are no limitations with applying the same rule to multiple fields.  Otherwise, if you have a specific issue, then please [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).  The comments section is not for answering new questions.